# Complete Time Machine restore is only partially recovering my files

Tags: time-machine, restore, folders, sidebar

I recently renamed my home folder on my new MacBook Pro (Retina, 13"). I restarted my computer not realising that it would result in a complete wipe of my drive. Previously having backed it up with Time Machine, I wasn't too worried though.

Looking through the Time Machine backup files, I also did see everything I had had previously saved, and since I have the backup on an external, I restarted the computer and pressed command+R to perform a complete restore.

About 78% through it seemed as if my external drive had failed (not responding, no progress). However, after a few moments my MacBook said the restore had been successful and restarted. Upon logging in, however, I saw that two very important folders were messed up - both of these I had added to the sidebar and the dock. Now, one of them was missing completely (a question mark in its place on the dock) and the other only had one file in it from a day ago.

Alarmed, I tried restoring the computer again, with the same results. Now even the backup files on my external don't have intact versions of the two folders. Furthermore, none of the data for my apps or any of my settings seem to have carried over.

If there's any way I can recover the two files, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Time Machine App, you may see the time line show you backup time, you can navigate the "important folders" at any backup time.

if you find the files you want, just restore it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that, founds quite frustrating.

Regarding

> I recently renamed my home folder on my new MacBook Pro (Retina, 13").
>   I restarted my computer not realising that it would result in a
>   complete wipe of my drive.

This should not have 'wiped' anything - but indeed the system will have difficulty logging in properly because the home folder contains all your user's login preferences etc.  (Apple really should pop up a warning if you rename your home folder.)

If you had just reverted the name of the home folder, you should have been golden (eg. by booting in Command-S single-user mode, mounting the drives as instructed, and

```
 mv /Users/HomeFolder_NewName /Users/HomeFolder_OriginalName
```

Regarding getting your files back, try the full TimeMachine Timeline restore as suggested above by nelson.

- Navigate to the folder that is missing files.
- Choose "Enter Time Machine" from the Time Machine menu item.  This
  should pull up the timeline of items in that folder.
- Scroll back through the timeline until you see that the folder is
  fully populated,
- Then choose "restore".  You may need to select all the files in the
  folder and then choose "Restore" to bring back all those files.

One issue I can foresee is if your backup drive was kind of full, maybe it's deleted some older backups - perhaps including the one with these missing files (would only happen if you ran a TM backup after the Full Restore as well).

Good luck.